# Alfresco 5.0.a/b doubled facets for d:mltext

Tags: search, solr, share, alfresco, faceted-search

It seems that facets doesn't work properly with multi language properties.
I did a simple test in Alfresco 5.0.a and 5.0.b on clean installation:

1. Created a text document in site.
2. Put description in English.
3. Changed browser language to French.
4. Added French version of the description.
5. Searched for the file name.
6. Found only one document which was just created.

The problem is that in Description facet on the left panel I have two descriptions - one English and one French.
Both points to the same file, but logically there should be only one description (depends on the browser's language).

[image]

Did anybody faced this problem? It seems like a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised an issue [ALF-21249](https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-21249)

And also found a workaround, which is a bit dirty, but works well.

Let's say you have a property with name `ccm:property` which has type `d:mltext` and you want to have facet for this property in English and French.

1. Define an aspect with two d:text properties: `ccm:propertyEn` and `ccm:propertyFr`
2. Apply this aspect to the type.
3. When you set the `ccm:property` set also `ccm:propertyEn` and `ccm:propertyFr`properties
4. Modify variable `facets` in `faceted-search.get.js` so that depends on the user's language one or another facet are shown:

```js
if (locale.substring(0, 2)== "fr")
  facetQName = "{http://www.ccm.com/model/ccm/1.0}propertyFr.__.u";
else
  facetQName = "{http://www.ccm.com/model/ccm/1.0}propertyEn.__.u";
facets.unshift(
{
  id: "FCTSRCH_FACET_DOCUMENT_TYPE",
  name: "alfresco/search/FacetFilters",
  config: {
    label: msg.get("faceted-search.facet-menu.facet.docType"),
    facetQName: facetQName,
    sortBy: "ALPHABETICALLY",
    hitThreshold: 1,
    minFilterValueLength: 5,
    maxFilters: 10,
    useHash: false
  }
});
```

Done! :)

Comment: Hello @streetturtle, do you (or anyone) know what mean these ".__.u"  hieroglyphs ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I'm not sure if it's a bug, but technically it looks like it should be.

Multilingual fields contains multiple text definitions of the same field. Solr indexes the field and sees there are 2 values (even though for the same field) so he creates a facet out of them.

Sure it's possible in the UI to filter out, Alfresco probably will need to do it (raise a JIRA so they can take a look). But in case of technical faceting/filtering it works like it should.

Comment: Thank you! I'll raise a ticket. For the filtering on UI side it seems quite hard to do since there is no any parameter which tells which language is used in response from solr.

Comment: I know it's probably difficult, but maybe combining both facet into 1 seems better. The value of both the facets match so that's probably your starting point on UI level. Second is to determine if the locale can be send.